# Docker performance, improve high cpu usage

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've got a shared Digital Ocean Premium AMD droplet with following stats:

```
2 vCPUs
2 GB
50 GB
3 TB
```

In that droplet got Docker with 3 containers running. Nothing else. When running `docker stats` here is the output:

```
CONTAINER ID   NAME                  CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O        PIDS
7f5557bad94b   traefik_1             0.01%     15.24MiB / 1.937GiB   0.77%     15.4MB / 20.5MB   135kB / 0B       10  
395e0555c552   mongodb               0.33%     109.3MiB / 1.937GiB   5.51%     23.4MB / 39.8MB   74.6MB / 918MB   37  
6a41254587d0   flask                 103.61%   220.9MiB / 1.937GiB   11.14%    182MB / 140MB     233kB / 0B       238
```

As you can see CPU usage of flask container is very high.

Here is Dockerfile for flask container:

```
FROM python:3.8.1-slim-buster


ENV WORKDIR=/usr/src/app
ENV USER=app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR $WORKDIR

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt $WORKDIR/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN adduser --system --group $USER
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY . $APP_HOME
RUN chown -R $USER:$USER $APP_HOME
USER $USER
```

Is there anything that can be done? Or do I need to upgrade the container? The application can have tens of websockets that are do something. Basically its a trading bot, so it does a lot of work with pandas, storing information etc.

Comment: Why do you think it should not use that much CPU? Do you have another installation you can compare to?

Comment: When there is no websockets open the app does not do anything other then wait. The CPU usage does not go down. Stays above 100

Comment: The problem is in the `.` of the `COPY . $APP_HOME` step, i.e. in the code which we don't see. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @TSlegaitis why it shouldn't be using that much ?